# laravel excel export - data storing as text instead of number

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to export an excel with all the data pushed in it.
After downloading the excel, the integer cells are stored as text with a small green triangle with an error

`The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe`

I also tried using `setColumnFormat` function to convert all the columns to `int` datatype, but didn't work

`$sheet->setColumnFormat(array('A:AP' => \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT::NUMBER));`

Also while pushing the data in the cell, I'm using
`number_format` function which didn't work either.

Looking for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be resolved once you remove `number_format()` This function returns `string` type instead of `number`. Please check [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) and [this quick example](https://paiza.io/projects/19xAhWPPW92B0WL5djbVgA)

Comment: Yes. Didn't know that `number_format` returns a string type before. So I changed my snippets accordingly.